# What is the difference between SequenceType and CollectionType in swift?

Tags: swift

Please explain the difference between `SequenceType`, `GeneratorType` and `CollectionType` in the Swift programming language.

Also, if I am implementing my own data structure what would be the advantage of using `SequenceType`, `GeneratorType` or `CollectionType` protocols?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

**[GeneratorType](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.2/protocol/GeneratorType/) ([IteratorProtocol in Swift 3](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/iteratorprotocol)):** `Generators` is something that can give the `next` element of some sequence, if there is no element it returns `nil`. `Generators` encapsulates iteration state and interfaces for iteration over a sequence.

A generator works by providing a single method, namely – `next()`, which simply returns the next value from the underlying `sequence`.

**Following classes Adopt GeneratorType Protocol:**

[DictionaryGenerator](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_DictionaryGenerator_Structure/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/struct/s:Vs19DictionaryGenerator), [EmptyGenerator](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_EmptyGenerator_Structure/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/struct/s:Vs14EmptyGenerator), more [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/iteratorprotocol#relationships).

---

**[SequenceType](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.2/protocol/SequenceType/) ([Sequence in Swift 3](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/sequence)):** A `Sequence` represent a series of values. `Sequence` is a type that can be iterated with a `for...in` loop.

Essentially a sequence is a generator factory; something that knows how to make generators for a sequence.

**Following classes Adopt SequenceType Protocol:**

[NSArray](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/cl/c:objc(cs)NSArray), [NSDictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/cl/c:objc(cs)NSDictionary), [NSSet](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/cl/c:objc(cs)NSSet) and [more](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/sequence#relationships).

---

**[CollectionType](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.2/protocol/CollectionType/) ([Collection in Swift 3](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/collection)):** `Collection` is a `SequenceType` that can be accessed via subscript and defines a `startIndex` and `endIndex`. `Collection` is a step beyond a sequence; individual elements of a collection can be accessed multiple times.

`CollectionType` inherits from `SequenceType`

**Following classes Adopt CollectionType Protocol:**

[Array](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Array_Structure/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/struct/s:Sa), [Dictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Dictionary_Structure/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/struct/s:Vs10Dictionary), [Set](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Set_Structure/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/struct/s:Vs3Set), [Range](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Range_Structure/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/struct/s:Vs5Range) and [more](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/collection#relationships).

---

Form more information you can see [this](http://nshipster.com/swift-collection-protocols/), [this](http://iosdeveloperzone.com/2014/10/13/swift-standard-library-generators-sequences-and-collections/), and [this](http://austinzheng.com/2015/01/24/swift-seq/)

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong. **1)** `Array`, `Dictionary` and `Set` all conform to `collectionType` (which itself implements SequenceType (that has a function named `next` which returns something that implements `GeneratorType`) )? **2)** Can you update your answer to include some of Swift Foundation types that conform to each of the 3 protocols mentioned?

Comment: Thanks. Can't you also subscript or get first and last index of NSArray or NSDictionary?