# How to convert code to Swift 4 because of undeclared types?

Tags: swift, xcode

I found some code that won't work in Swift 4. The thing is that SequenceType and GeneratorOf are undeclared and I'm not sure how to convert this code with new protocols in Swift 4.

I tried changing SequenceType to Sequence and GeneratorOf to Iterator, but not sure how it actually works.

```
public struct WeakSet<T> where T: AnyObject, T: Hashable {
    typealias Element = T

    /// Maps Element hashValues to arrays of Entry objects.
    /// Invalid Entry instances are culled as a side effect of add() and remove()
    /// when they touch an object with the same hashValue.
    private var contents: [Int: [Entry<Element>]] = [:]

    public init(_ objects: T...) {
        self.init(objects)
    }

    public init(_ objects: [T]) {
        for object in objects {
            insert(newElement: object)
        }
    }

    /// Add an element to the set.
     mutating func insert(newElement: Element) {
        var entriesAtHash = validEntriesAtHash(hashValue: newElement.hashValue)
        var found = false
        for entry in entriesAtHash {
            if let existingElement = entry.element {
                if existingElement == newElement {
                    found = true
                    break
                }
            }
        }
        if found {
            return
        }
        let entry = Entry(element: newElement)
        entriesAtHash.append(entry)
        contents[newElement.hashValue] = entriesAtHash
    }

    /// Remove an element from the set.
     mutating func remove(removeElement: Element) {
        let entriesAtHash = validEntriesAtHash(hashValue: removeElement.hashValue)
        let entriesMinusElement = entriesAtHash.filter { $0.element != removeElement }
        if entriesMinusElement.isEmpty {
            contents[removeElement.hashValue] = nil
        }
        else {
            contents[removeElement.hashValue] = entriesMinusElement
        }
    }

    // Does the set contain this element?
     func contains(element: Element) -> Bool {
        let entriesAtHash = validEntriesAtHash(hashValue: element.hashValue)
        for entry in entriesAtHash {
            if entry.element == element {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }

    private func validEntriesAtHash(hashValue: Int) -> [Entry<Element>] {
        if let entries = contents[hashValue] {
            return entries.filter {
                $0.element != nil
            }
        }
        else {
            return []
        }
    }
}

private struct Entry<T> where T: AnyObject, T: Hashable {
    typealias Element = T
    weak var element: Element?
}

// MARK: SequenceType
extension WeakSet: SequenceType {
    typealias Generator = GeneratorOf<T>

    /// Creates a generator for the items of the set.
    public func generate() -> Generator {
        // This is not straightforward because we need to iterate over the arrays and then their contents.
        var contentsGenerator = contents.values.enumerated()         // generates arrays of entities
        var entryGenerator = contentsGenerator.next()?.generate()  // generates entries
        return Swift.GeneratorOf {
            // Note: If entryGenerator is nil, the party is over. No more.
            if let element = entryGenerator?.next()?.element {
                return element
            }
            else { // Ran out of entities in this array. Get the next one, if there is one.
                entryGenerator = contentsGenerator.next()?.generate()
                return entryGenerator?.next()?.element
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, I'm getting undeclared type error for SequenceType and GeneratorOf, and I kind of don't understand this generate() method at the bottom.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30565875/what-is-the-difference-between-sequencetype-and-collectiontype-in-swift) might be a good place to start

Comment: Yeah, I looked at it already. That gave me some understanding but not enough to figure this out myself. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing here is that I wanted Weak Reference Set. But I found another solution. If anyone needs it here it is:

```
class WeakObject<T: AnyObject>: Equatable, Hashable {
    weak var object: T?
    init(object: T) {
        self.object = object
    }

    var hashValue: Int {
        if var object = object { return UnsafeMutablePointer<T>(&object).hashValue }
        return 0
    }

    static func == (lhs: WeakObject<T>, rhs: WeakObject<T>) -> Bool {
        return lhs.object === rhs.object
    }
}

class WeakObjectSet<T: AnyObject> {
    var objects: Set<WeakObject<T>>

    init() {
        self.objects = Set<WeakObject<T>>([])
    }

    init(objects: [T]) {
        self.objects = Set<WeakObject<T>>(objects.map { WeakObject(object: $0) })
    }

    var allObjects: [T] {
        return objects.compactMap { $0.object }
    }

    func contains(_ object: T) -> Bool {
        return self.objects.contains(WeakObject(object: object))
    }

    func addObject(_ object: T) {
        self.objects.formUnion([WeakObject(object: object)])
    }

    func addObjects(_ objects: [T]) {
        self.objects.formUnion(objects.map { WeakObject(object: $0) })
    }
}
```